# multi-language cms by JSON

Tags: json, database, content-management-system, multilingual

i need your help by using your experience and answer me if the following approach will be good with a multi language content.

all of us know the common technique if you have a multilanguage database:

```
Language table
Article
Article_content
id | article_id | lang_id | content
```

but i want to use new approach by using JSON to insert content and this will be as following

```
Article Table
ID|content
1 | { "en":"lorem ipsum dollar....", "fr":"lorem ipsum dollar...." };
```

all i need to know, why there is no one using this approach while build CMS and what are the pros and cons of this choice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using PHP (which I use and can answer), PHP provides encoding and decoding for json. Knowing that, you can just work with your every day arrays and encode/decode them for JSON.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

A great benefit would be if you work with your data with an API. You can more easily process the JSON data with javascript, php, or any language of your choice.